# Java Binary Search Tree with JSS2 Homework

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm just trying to add an element to a binary search tree but I get a NullPointerException.

I hate to ask but I really have had an awful teacher with the inability to clearly explain anything and I've tried for hours trying to understand. If someone could please just send me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it cause I really do want to learn.

```
package jss2;
import java.util.*;
import jss2.exceptions.*;
import jss2.*;

public class LinkedBinaryTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Creating the tree");
        BinarySearchTreeADT<String> tree = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<String>();

        tree.addElement ("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code in LinkedBinarySearchTree and BinarySearchTreeADT ? The problem is certainly in one of the constructors.

Comment: Or the problem could be in the `addElement` method, can you also show the code for that? And a stack trace of the exception.

Comment: The Code being called appears to be faculty-written, here: http://faculty.washington.edu/moishe/javademos/jss2/

Comment: Yes that's the code we need to use and we are not allowed to change it.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. Do you have a stack-trace at the point where the exception is thrown?

Comment: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at     jss2.LinkedBinarySearchTree.addElement(LinkedBinarySearchTree.java:50)
 at jss2.LinkedBinaryTree.main(LinkedBinaryTree.java:14)'

Comment: Just downloaded all the .java files and your test code works just fine. So I'm not really sure where to point you, except that you can maybe wipe everything, download **the .java files** and try your code again. There may be a naming conflict with your class, but this is highly unlikely to cause a `NullPointerException` (though you may as well try renaming it).